# JMeter - Should I remove Redirect from recorded script?

Tags: jmeter

I used the Blazemeter Chrome plug-in to record.  When the UserID is checked, browser is redirected to another URL.  This redirect is recorded in the script.

Want to ask:

1. I read that the redirect will occur during the UserID check if I have Follow Redirects checked ?  Is this correct ?  The reason I ask is that I saw some extra HTTP request generated but they are not the same URL as the redirect which was sent from the server.
2. So I can actually just remove the redirect URL recorded ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JMeter test [must generate the same network footpring as the real browser does](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

So you can use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to compare the number/nature of the requests which originate from JMeter and from the real browser, the requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which needs to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

If [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler redirects automatically and the next request basically duplicates the redirected one - remove the recorded one.

If automatic redirect is causing troubles and you're not able to extract dynamic elements because they're "hidden" in 2nd level of sub-results - disable redirection in the HTTP Request sampler and leave the recorded separate request which mimics redirection.

[image]